# Rich Edit Control changes the DialogBox return value behavior?

Tags: c++, winapi, richedit, dialog

I'm a bit puzzled: i created a dialogbox with `Edit Control`, then i noticed the text isn't word wrapped, so i googled and found out that i should use `Rich Edit Control` instead. So i did. Now, when ever there is a `Rich Edit Control` in my dialog box, the functionality changes: without `Rich Edit Control` the dialogbox returned either `IDOK` or `IDCANCEL`, which i handle outside of the message handler code. BUT, if there is a `Rich Edit Control` anywhere in the dialogbox, it always returns something else than `IDOK`, before i even click any buttons in the dialog box: the dialogbox seems to not even be created at all.

Here is the message handler:

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK MyDialogBox(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    switch(message){
        case WM_INITDIALOG: {
            SetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_EDIT1, (LPCTSTR)some_string.c_str());
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch(LOWORD(wParam)){
                case IDOK: case IDCANCEL: {
                    EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
                    return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
                }
            }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

And here is the code where i use the dialogbox:

```
if(DialogBox(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), hWnd, MyDialogBox) == IDOK){
    // without rich edit control it goes here or below depending on the user choice.
}else{
    // with rich edit it always goes here.
}
```

So, the ultimate question here is: how do i get this thing work like it works with normal `Edit Control` ?

**Edit:** when it fails, the values are: -1 for DialogBox(), and 0 for GetLastError(), if that helps ?

**Edit2:** Problem solved by antinome's [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/c325a6ab-5e58-4970-a123-cda46fb096ff/): include `afxwin.h` and call `AfxInitRichEdit2()` at the window `WM_CREATE` message.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what value is being returned by `DialogBox()`. Also, what value does [`GetLastError()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) return if you call it after DialogBox returns?

Comment: @antinome, -1 for dialogbox(), and 0 for getlasterror().

Comment: Is that *all* the code?  Or is your code missing *break* in one or more case statements?

Comment: A multiline edit control is word wrapped if ES_AUTOHSCROLL is not specified. See ES_MULTILINE in [Edit Control Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775464%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @Hans, yes its all my code. the bug isnt about the code btw: whenever i add that Rich Edit Control, the dialogbox stops from functioning as expected, and when i delete the Rich Edit Control, it works fine again! And this all happens even without referencing to this Rich Edit Control at all in my code.

Comment: @Sertac, thanks! i could have never guessed it was ES_AUTOHSCROLL that enables wordwrapping.

Comment: Can you try creating a Rich Edit control **not** in a dialog box? Such as in your main application window. If that fails, too, then take a look and tell us how you are linking/loading/initializing the `dll` or `lib` file where the control is coming from.  (e.g. Riched20.dll or Msftedit.dll)

Comment: Also check out **[Rich edit control preventing Dialog Box from opening](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/c325a6ab-5e58-4970-a123-cda46fb096ff/)**  (although I guess you probably are happy now with the regular edit control)

Comment: @antinome, checked the link and the answer is to include `afxwin.h` and call `AfxInitRichEdit2()` at the window `WM_CREATE` message. Thanks! if you want you can add it as an answer and i can accept it.

Comment: Have written it up as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[This thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/c325a6ab-5e58-4970-a123-cda46fb096ff/)** has some good tips for resolving this problem. To summarize:

If using pure WinAPI:

- Make sure to call `LoadLibrary("RichEd20.dll");` or `LoadLibrary("Msftedit.dll");`. The latter is the newer version of the control.
- According to **[Rich Edit Control in raw Win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85427/rich-edit-control-in-raw-win32)**, you can also call `InitCommonControlsEx()` with the appropriate class constant (`MSFTEDIT_CLASS` apparently) — but it's only needed if you want windows visual styles to work.

If using MFC:

- Make sure to call `AfxInitRichEdit2()` at initialization stage, for example in `InitInstance()`